# createdb typegraphql-example password authentication failed for user WINDOWS

Tags: postgresql

im new in postgresSQL
and when i try to create a new database with the command createdb
i got this error:

createdb: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "danie"

i found the solution on windows thats why im creating this for helping someone that have the same error

first you need to add the postgresSQl commands to windows cmd:
search in internet how, it is easy

second, as you can see the error is that authentication failed for your windows username

so you need to create a new user in pdAdmin4 with the same name of your windows username:

[here you can know how](https://www.guru99.com/postgresql-create-alter-add-user.html)

thats all, that work for me

Comment: how to add postgresSQL commands to the windows cmd??: https://linuxhint.com/connect-to-postgresql-database-command-line-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to add postgresSQL to the cmd windows?
https://linuxhint.com/connect-to-postgresql-database-command-line-windows/

first you need to add the postgresSQl commands to windows cmd: search in internet how, it is easy

second, as you can see the error is that authentication failed for your windows username

so you need to create a new user in pdAdmin4 with the same name of your windows username:

[here you can know how](https://www.guru99.com/postgresql-create-alter-add-user.html)

thats all, that work for me